# Fetch PDF from BLOB and create zip in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, header, blob

I have blob stored in Database and successfully converted it into PDF. I am using this code.

```
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$this->pdfName);
        header("Content-length: ".strlen($res[0]['comp_statement']));
        $this->pdf = $res[0]['comp_statement']
        echo $res[0]['comp_statement'];
```

There are two option in Content-Disposition ethier you can download it or show it on web page.
I do not want to show or download. I want it to place in zip directory which I am creating dynamically.

Here the code for zip archive

```
     $zip = new ZipArchive;       
      $zipName = $this->currentCompYear.'.zip';
      if ($zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
        if(!$zip->locateName($this->currentCompYear)) {
            $zip->addEmptyDir($this->currentCompYear);
        } 
        if(!$zip->locateName($regionDir)) {
            $zip->addEmptyDir($regionDir1);
        }
        if(!$zip->locateName($managerDir)) {
            $zip->addEmptyDir($managerDir1);
        }

        $zip -> addFile($this->pdf));// I want to add my pdf file here
        $zip->close();
        ob_clean();
        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$zipName);
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipName));
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        readfile($zipName);
```

Any Clue.

Comment: that's not really clear. You don't want to download or show, so why all these headers ? Where does the zip file go after you created it ? With `readfile` it's read and printed, so it will surely be downloaded somehow by the client browser

Comment: @Pierre I want to download zip file but do not want to download only pdf.  I can remove the these header if it is only used to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need any of that header and echo stuff if you just want to store the contents to a file, use `file_put_contents()` to store the pdf, then pass the file name and not the contents to addFile() of your Zip function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php